Derivation of SECOND-order time-dependent perturbation theory (TDPT)
Are there any detailed derivation of the second oder term of TDPT? I found a pdf note on google, but an important equation in this pdf maybe wrong.

How can I get (17) from (15) and (16)? It seems that (17) equals to
$\bar{a_i}(t) \frac{da_i(t)}{dt}$ instead of $\frac{1}{a_i(t)} \frac{da_i(t)}{dt}$, but I can't derive $\bar{a_i}(t) = \frac{1}{a_i(t)}$.

I think I know what happens. The perturbation is turned on from $t = -\infty$, so adiabatic theorem should be applied, this is why $|a_i(t)|^2 = 1$.

I don't see how asking about a derivation done in a text can be construed as homework or exercise like.

In perturbation theory you have $a = 1 - ix + O(x^2)$ and $1/a = 1 + ix +O(x^2)$ with small real $x$. Therefore, up to second-order terms, $1/a$ is equal to $\overline{a} = 1 + ix +O(x^2)$ and formula (17) is correct.

I find a more detailed derivation in the section 5.9 of the book J.J. Sakurai, Modern Quantum Mechanics 2nd ed
